# vuex: unknown action type -> Vue 3 with Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am implementing vuex in my application with Vue 3 and typescript. I'm getting the following error when I call the function : [vuex] unknown action type: documentModule/deleteDocument

I'm going to leave some of the implemented code below in case someone knows how to tell me the error.

**documet-module.ts**

```
const state = {
    fileDto: FileDto
}

const mutations = {
    DELETE_DOCUMENT(state: any, payload: any) {
        return true;
    },
}

const actions = {
    async deleteDocument({ commit }: any, id: number) {
        await itiHttpService.delete(API.documents + '/' + id, null).then((response: any) => {
            commit('DELETE_DOCUMENT', response.data)
        });
    }
}

const getters = {
}

const documentModule = {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    mutations,
    actions,
    getters
}

export default documentModule;
```

**index.ts**

```
export default createStore({
    modules: {
        documentModule
    }
});
```

**main.ts**

```
const app = createApp(App);
const emitter = mitt();

app.use(router);
app.use(i18n);
app.use(store);
app.provide('emitter', emitter);
app.config.globalProperties.$appInfo = appInfo;
app.mount('#app');
```

**document-list.ts**

```
function deleteDocument() {

    const message: string = `¿Eliminar documento${((selectedRowKeys.value.length === 1) ? "" : "s")}?`;

    MessageService.confirm(message, null, async (res) => {
        if (res) {
            for (const element of selectedRowKeys.value) {
                store.dispatch('documentModule/deleteDocument', element);
            }
            dataGrid.value.instance.refresh();
        }
    });
}
```

Please, I need someone to help me find the error.

Answer (score 0):

What you're showing should work (demonstrated below). You didn't include the imports in your code but are you sure there isn't something wrong there?

```js
const store = Vuex.createStore({
  modules: {
    documentModule: {
      namespaced: true,
      state: {
        fileDto: 'abcd'
      },
      mutations: {
        DELETE_FILE(state, payload) {
          console.log('mutated');
          state.fileDto = null;
        }
      },
      actions: {
        deleteFile({
          commit
        }, id) {
          console.log('called!');
          commit('DELETE_FILE');
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
const app = Vue.createApp({});
app.use(store);
store.dispatch('documentModule/deleteFile');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@4"></script>

<html>

<body>
  <div id="#app"></div>
</body>

</html>
```